# Evaluate $\displaystyle\int_V xy^9z^8 (1-x-y-z)^4\,dx\,dy\,dz$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate $\displaystyle\int_V xy^9z^8 (1-x-y-z)^4\,dx\,dy\,dz,$ where $V$ is the pyramidal region $x, y, z \geq 0, x+ y+ z \leq 1.$

So the integral is equivalent to $$\int_0^1\displaystyle\int_0^{1-z} \int_0^{1-y-z} xy^9z^8(1-x-y-z)^4\,dx\,dy\,dz.$$

I can evaluate this directly, which gives the answer $\dfrac{9!8!4!}{25!},$ but that method is way too tedious. Is there a faster approach?

Comment: Let $$V=\Big\{(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)\in\Bbb{R}^n\Big| x_i\ge0\; \forall i \wedge \sum_{i=1}^nx_i\leq 1\Big\}$$ and $\lambda$ is the volume measure.  If $x_0=1-\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$, then 
$$\int_V \prod_{i=0}^n x_i^{\alpha_i-1} d\lambda(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\frac{\prod_{i=0}^n\Gamma(\alpha_i)}{\Gamma\left(\sum_{i=0}^n\alpha_i\right)}=\frac{\prod_{i=0}^n (\alpha_i-1)!}{\left(\sum_{i=0}^n\alpha_i -1\right)!}$$ for all $\alpha_0,\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_n>0$.  You can prove this by induction on $n$ and by using the beta function.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool This should really be expanded into an answer so that this doesn't sit around unanswered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Beta function is defined by
$$B(p, q)=\int_0^1{x^{p-1}(1-x)^{q-1}}dx \,\, (p, q>0)$$
with a useful property that
$$B(p, q)=\frac{\Gamma(p)\Gamma(q)}{\Gamma(p+q)}$$
The proof is almost straightforward. Now with this tool we can easily compute integrals of following form:
$$\int_0^a{x^{p-1}(a-x)^{q-1}}dx$$
by substituting $ax$ into $x$ as follows.
$$\int_0^1{(ax)^{p-1}(a-ax)^{q-1}a}dx=a^{p+q-1}\int_0^1{x^{p-1}(1-x)^{q-1}}dx=a^{p+q-1}B(p, q).$$
And your integral is indeed an iteration of calculation of this kind of integral:

$$
\begin{align}
& \int_0^1{\int_0^{1-z}{\int_0^{1-y-z}{(1-x-y-z)^{p-1}x^{q-1}y^{r-1}z^{s-1}}}}dxdydz \\
& =\int_0^1{\int_0^{1-z}{y^{r-1}z^{s-1}\int_0^{1-y-z}{(1-x-y-z)^{p-1}x^{q-1}}}}dxdydz\\
& =\int_0^1{\int_0^{1-z}{(1-y-z)^{p+q-1}y^{r-1}z^{s-1}B(p, q)}}dydz\\
& =B(p, q)\int_0^1{z^{s-1}\int_0^{1-z}{(1-y-z)^{p+q-1}y^{r-1}}}dydz\\
& =B(p, q)\int_0^1{z^{s-1}(1-z)^{p+q+r-1}B(p+q, r)}dydz\\
& =B(p, q)B(p+q, r)B(p+q+r, s)\\
& =\frac{\Gamma(p)\Gamma(q)\Gamma(r)\Gamma(s)}{\Gamma(p+q+r+s)}.\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: This is an elegant answer +1